# How to find the tunnel Type?

Tags: networking, tcp, vpn

I am trying to find out the type of the tunnel used for a vpn.. I am trying to determing if the tunnel is tcp or udp.. how do I do that? When I observe the tunnel traffic I am not able to observe anything! In the sense that packets are sent as such..

Comment: How are you observing the tunnel traffic? A packet capture should let you easily see transport protocol is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to observe the traffic on the physical network connection, not the traffic in the tunnel itself:

- Setup a network packet capture program, such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), to capture the traffic on the "real" network interface e.g. your cabled Ethernet connection. On Linux it would be something along the lines of `eth0`.
- (Optional) Shutdown as many processes that use the network as possible.
- Cause as much traffic through the VPN tunnel as possible - e.g. download a large file.
- Watch in your capture program for any change - the tunnel traffic should now stand out due to sheer volume.

Keep in mind that if you are using an IPSec tunnel, the packets will be [ESP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulating_Security_Payload#Encapsulating_Security_Payload), which is neither TCP nor UDP.